Launch DBeaver with custom configuration/connection
I am working in several projects where every one has its own database connections.
So far, I have been using DBeaver, adding the connections by hand, but at the end, having the connections, data, SQL scripts, tabs, etc. for all the projects in the same place results in a chaotic environment.
So, I am trying to create a tool able to launch DBeaver which the configuration (i.e. connections) specific to a project.
Looking at the docs, it should be an easy task, but I can not get it to work.
I have tried multiple combinations of parameters for the -con argument (create, save, connect, openConsole, url, folder, database, etc.) but I am not able to open dbeaver UI with a new connection.
For instance:
dbeaver-ce   \
  -data .    \
  -con "driver=sqlite|database=one.sqlite|folder=/home/salva/projects/one|name=one|openConsole=true|connect=true|save=true|create=true" \
  -f

I am unable to find the exact spell that would make it work and would appreciate any advice on the matter!
Update: It seems it was a PEBCAK, I had not noticed I already had a DBeaver instance open in another workspace, and because of that, nothing was apparently happening when I run the command with the new connection, I found that adding the -f flag (without its required argument), would made DBeaver to appear but then, -con was not handled, probably because of the broken -f!
In any case, it is working now!

Welcome to the DBA.SE community. You write that you are not able to get it to work, but you don't include any error messages in your question. Could you [edit] your question and provide additional details? Thanks.
